# Why I need to login two times to apply changes to AD group membership or GPO filtering?

Tags: active-directory

If I add a user to a group in AD, to reflect that change on a computer (see it on gpresult in security groups), I need to sign in and off the user session two times. Also the same happens when I add the user to delegation list in a GPO as deny on apply this gpo.

¿is this the usual behavior? I think is not, one log off should be sufficient. But this happens consistently.

Is something broken in my AD?
The client logon server and the DC where I made the changes is the same.

Also, no matter how many gpupdate I do within the user session, still two logins needed.

Comment: Is it possible replication delay is a factor?

Comment: I don't think so, as I said the logon server is the same DC that I made the changes.